# TeXLive 2011: pdfLaTeX does not convert eps to pdf for eps files in subdirectories

Tags: pdftex, texlive, eps

As from 2010, TexLive has been converting `.eps` files directly to pdf file if the compilation is done with PDFLaTeX. Thus a file named

```
coilsans.eps
```

will be automatically be converted to a file named

```
coilsans-eps-converted-to.pdf
```

However I find that the conversion is done if the `.eps` file is located in the root directory as the main `.tex` file. If the `.eps` files happen to be located in another folder, then PdfLaTeX complains  e.g.

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `../test/classi-eps-converted-to.pdf' not  found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.130 ...ludegraphics[scale=1]{../test/classi.eps}
                                              }
? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

How to instruct PDFLaTeX to search in the right directories?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the option `-shell-escape` to your compilation options.

Alternatively, instead of having the EPS images in a folder at the same level (but in a different subdirectory), you could just place it in a subdirectory of your root `.tex` file. Then `pdflatex` will not complain about the conversion and inclusion of EPS files.

Comment: @ Werner Thanks. Does -shell-escape is to be put after pdfLaTeX.exe like in pdfLaTeX -shell-escape myfile.tex ? Actually I have the file in a folder in my tex root directory. Even if I have {/test/classi.eps}, PdfLaTeX still complains. 1 vote up.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: Yes, `pdflatex -shell-escape myfile.tex`. I was able to reproduce your error if I included `../test/XX.eps`, but had no problems with inclusion of `test/XX.eps` under `pdflatex`. The `-shell-escape` option solved it in both cases. The problem deals with "restricted mode," which led me to [this thread](http://macosx-tex.576846.n2.nabble.com/epstopdf-problem-restricted-mode-td6008485.html). I found that I had the `shell_escape = p` setting in my `texmf.cnf` file.

Comment: @ Werner I have the texmf.cnf file also as yours with shell_escape = p in C:\texlive\2011\texmf\web2c. My mistake was to put {/test/classi.eps} and not just {test/classi.eps}. Thanks. It works now.

Comment: (Old question, but...) Can anybody explain *why* `shell-escape` is necessary only if `eps` files are in subdirectories?

Comment: @Ross: You mean it works if the EPS files are in the main folder, but not in subfolders?

Comment: That was my interpretation of the OP's problem - "However I find that the conversion is done if the .eps file is located in the root directory as the main  .tex file. If the .eps files happen to be located in another folder, then PdfLaTeX complains".

Comment: @Ross: I'd imagine path searching requires external application.

Comment: It seems to me that your answer is saying `shell-escape` is the solution to OP's problem, which is all about figure placement in subdirectories. I thought `shell-escape` had to do with converting eps to pdf in general.

Comment: @Ross: Indeed it does. `shell-escape` allows access to the command shell for running external programs. See [What does `--shell-escape` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88740/5764)

Comment: So how does that help with OP's question? (This is my point of confusion all along!) OP **was already** able to convert - "the conversion is done", but only if they are not in subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

Try this kind of folder structure. I had the same error but overcome by using like this.

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\ifpdf
    \graphicspath{{Introduction/IntroductionFigs/PNG/}{Introduction/IntroductionFigs/PDF/}{Introduction/IntroductionFigs/}}
\else
    \graphicspath{{Introduction/IntroductionFigs/EPS/}{Introduction/IntroductionFigs/}}
\fi
```