# What does --shell-escape do?

Tags: compiling, shell-escape

I stumbled upon an example, which needed to be compiled with the additional option `--shell-escape`. Using this option it worked just fine, but I'm curious:

> Why or when is this option needed and what does it actually do?

Comment: If I'm not wrong I believe that this option enables TeX to execute other commands during the process. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76105/14757

Comment: Have you checked [What are `\immediate` & `\write18` and how does one use them?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20444/16595)? In short: “No `\write18` without `--shell-escape` (minus a few safe exceptions).”

Comment: Additional note: `-shell-escape` or `--shell-escape` for TeXLive or `-enable-write18` or `--enable-write18` for MikTeX does the same thing.

Comment: I disagree with the suggested closure. None of the linked threads mentions `--shell-escape` is such way that it would be obvious to non-experienced users.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Sometimes, it is useful to be able to run external commands from inside the tex file : it allows for example to externalize some typesetting, or to use external tools like bibtex. This is available via the `\write18` tex primitive.

The problem is that it allows for almost everything. A tex file is meant to be portable, and one shouldn't have to fear any security issue when compiling a third-party file. So by default, this primitive is disabled.

If an user needs to use it, he needs to explicitely tell the compiler that he trusts the author of the file with shell interaction, and that's exactly the point of the optional `--shell-escape` argument.

Comment: Can you please provide a working example where we can see how is this command written inside a LaTeX document? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You can for example see the end of the last snippet in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139734/9517) where they use `\write18` to compile a `.tex` into `.dvi` and convert the `.dvi` to `.ps` to `.pdf`.