# Changing index delim_0 does not work on Mactex with Texlive distribution

Tags: texlive, mactex, delimiters

I am trying to compile a book with multiple indexes. I am using indextools package with splitindex. I need to modify the index delimiter so I have created a .ist file with this content:

```
delim_0 ": \\ "  
delim_1 ": \\ "  
delim_2 ": \\ "
```

here is also my functional example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage[makeindex,splitindex]{indextools}
\makeindex[
      name=person, 
      title=INDEX of Persons, 
      program=makeindex,
      options={-s idxconf.ist},
          ]
\makeindex[
      name=word,
      title=Index of Words,
      program=makeindex,
      options={-s idxconf.ist},
          ]
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

Einstein\index[person]{Einstein}
\blindtext
\newpage

Heisenberg\index[person]{Heisenberg} % Person index
\blindtext[3]
\index[word]{foo}\index[person]{Bohr}
\index[word]{bar}
\blindtext

\printindex[person] 
\printindex[word] 

\end{document}
```

I am using Mactex with Texlive and the delimiter is not changed.
Same code compiled on a windows pc is working just fine.
Is there a way to make it work on mac?

Comment: If your aim is to print the entry followed by a colon and a double space, use ``": \\ "`` (colon, space, double backslash, space). Of course, no `</br>`.

Comment: I am sorry the `</br>` was an error from my side while inserting the code. the delim is as you mentioned `": \\ "`(quote, colon, space, double blackslash, space, quotes).

Comment: Where are you saving `idxconf.ist`?

Comment: Did you use the `--shell-escape` option when running latex? It doesn't work for me (even on windows) without that.

Comment: @egreg `idxconf.ist` is in the same folder with the tex file.

Comment: @Dan Thank you! it saved my day! I have added the `--shell-escape` on my Texmaker preferences and now is working as is suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete the question: As has been pointed out by Dan and egreg in the comments, you need to make sure that (1) you use the option `--shell-escape` when running LaTeX and (2) the `.ist`-file is saved in the same folder as the `.tex`-file.

Two additional points:

(1) You need `--shell-escape` because you are invoking an external program. Some infos: [What does --shell-escape do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88740/what-does-shell-escape-do)

(2): It can be advisable to wrap the three lines your `idxconf.ist` in a `filecontents`-environment so the `.ist`-file doesn’t straggle the next time you make use of configuring indices for another document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage[makeindex,splitindex]{indextools}
\makeindex[
  name=person, 
  title=INDEX of Persons, 
  program=makeindex,
  options={-s idxconf.ist},
      ]
\makeindex[
  name=word,
  title=Index of Words,
  program=makeindex,
  options={-s idxconf.ist},
      ]
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{filecontents}{idxconf.ist}
  delim_0 ": \\ "  
  delim_1 ": \\ "  
  delim_2 ": \\ "  
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Einstein\index[person]{Einstein}
\blindtext
\newpage

Heisenberg\index[person]{Heisenberg} % Person index
\blindtext[3]
\index[word]{foo}\index[person]{Bohr}
\index[word]{bar}
\blindtext

\printindex[person] 
\printindex[word] 

\end{document}
```