# How to handle this error while running LaTeX?

Tags: errors, packages, minted, shell-escape

What is the reason for the following error?

> Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.

Comment: It's because you haven't invoked the `-shell-escape` flag. It's pretty clear, in my opinion.

Comment: Run your latex with `-shell-escape` (e.g. `pdflatex -shell-escape`).

Comment: For a few guides how to enable sell escape in some popular editors, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99475/how-to-invoke-latex-with-the-shell-escape-flag-in-texmakerx https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82699/how-to-enable-shell-escape-in-texworks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039856/how-do-i-add-the-shell-escape-option-in-texshop

Comment: @Schweinebacke Yes, same question, but there also nobody explained anything about shell-escape.

Comment: @KeksDose: [What does --shell-escape do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88740/what-does-shell-escape-do) Perhaps this would be the better duplicate. But if I retract my vote I cannot vote for another duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

The package minted uses an external software »pygments«, written in Python. So pdfLaTeX needs to run »third party software«. This brings security issues: the external software can do anything, as far as your rights on the computer allow that.

Be aware of this when you start pdfLaTeX with `-shell-escape`. Pygments is used a lot, so if there were an issue, somebody would probably notice it. But if you ever start experimenting with Lua programms of whatever source, maybe think twice.

By the way, the name »shell-escape« refers to the fact that the external software is started via a system call in a shell of the OS.