# Package markdown failing with Miktex

Tags: miktex, markdown

I'm using Miktex 2.9 for Windows. When compiling:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{markdown}
\begin{document}

\begin{markdown}
| xyz | abc |
| --- |: --: |
| 0 | 5 | 
|5 |1 |
\end{markdown}

\end{document}
```

with `miktex-pdflatex.exe` (running as administrator), I get:

> Package markdown Error: I can not access the shell.

Note: The package `markdown` has been installed (automatically downloaded by Miktex) when I first compiled this code.

Comment: You need to run with shell escape and if I'm not mistaking it is based on Lua and therefore requires LuaLaTeX.

Comment: If I understand http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf correctly you need to enable `shell-escape`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88740/35864

Comment: @TeXnician is doesn't requires lualatex it works with pdflatex too. But with pdflatex it must be able to call luatex and so needs shell-escape.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, okay, but at least the shell-escape part was correct.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Now it compiles successfully with `--shell-escape` but the table still isn't rendered as a table... Any idea?

Comment: The table does not work for me either, but other markdown instructions work just fine. That makes me think that this table syntax is nor supported (at least not without further options). I could find nothing on a first glance into the manual.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88741/27733) and in comments, a *partial* solution is to do:

```
miktex-pdflatex.com --shell-escape mydocument.tex
```

instead of

```
miktex-pdflatex.com mydocument.tex
```

But then, even if compilation works,

```
begin{markdown}
| xyz | abc |
| --- |: --: |
| 0 | 5 | 
|5 |1 |
\end{markdown}
```

is still not rendered, so probably the `markdown` package doesn't support tables.

Comment: A wild guess, did you try to place a space before the first colon in the separator line: `| --- | : --: |` and in the data line `| 5 | 1 |`. Maybe also try without the colons

Comment: Instead of use markdown in LateX, you will obtain better work flows using LaTeX in markdown. The key word is Rmarkdown. Even if you are not planning use R in any way,  it worth install  pandoc and Rstudio to use that as an markdown editor.

Comment: Since the release of [version 2.8.0](https://github.com/Witiko/markdown/releases/tag/2.8.0), the Markdown package supports tables.