# imakeidx biblatex indexes not being placed in the correct locations

Tags: biblatex, indexing, imakeidx

I am attempting to create three indexes for a document (subject, author and title) but the author and subject indexes are being loaded into the incorrect sections. I have tried changing `\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}` `to DeclareIndexFieldFormat{default}` and modifying `{default}` to other strings like `indexname` but to no avail. Loading splitindex with `\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}` causes TexWorks to crash too so not sure if that is relevant or needed in this case.

```
%! MWE Example
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex
% arara: xindy: {modules: [texindy], codepage: utf8, language: english}
% arara: lualatex: {shell: yes}
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[backend=biber,      
        hyperref=true,          
        indexing=true,                  
        natbib=true,        
        ]{biblatex}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Che20,
author = {Chen, Keqiang and Wang, Cong and Peng, Zhuoyin and Qi, Kun and Guo, Zhinan and Zhang, Yupeng and Zhang, Han},
title = {{The chemistry of colloidal semiconductor nanocrystals: From metal-chalcogenides to emerging perovskite}},
year = {2020}
}
@article{Hak20,
author = {Hakkoymaz, Orhun and Mazi, Hidayet},
title = {{An immobilized invertase enzyme for the selective determination of sucrose in fruit juices}},
year = {2020}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeindex[intoc=true,
            program=xindy,
            title={Subject Index}]       
\makeindex[intoc=true,
             title={Author Index},
             program=xindy,
             name=names]
                    
{\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
   \usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[names]}
     {\namepartfamily}
     {\namepartgiven}
     {\namepartprefix}
     {\namepartsuffix}}}
     
\makeindex[intoc=true,          
             title={Title Index},
             program=xindy,
             name=titles]   
             
\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:title}{\index[titles]}{#1}}%

\begin{document}
\cite{Che20, Hak20}
\printindex
\printindex[titles]
\printindex[names]
\end{document}
```

The subject index (the default index with no name= attached) is loading the authors:

[image: Subject index with author names]

Whereas the author index is loading nothing even though I have called them in the correct order at the end of my MWE:

[image: Blank author index]

I want to use xindy as I like its formatting but it is causing me grief and I do not know if I am even calling it with `arara` correctly either, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an excess pair of curly braces around the `\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}`. This pair of braces keeps the definition local, which means that it is immediately discarded. So the name indexing does not use your new `names` index.

Remove the curly braces around `\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}`.

```
%! MWE Example
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex
% arara: xindy: {modules: [texindy], codepage: utf8, language: english}
% arara: lualatex: {shell: yes}
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
        indexing=true,
        natbib=true,
        ]{biblatex}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeindex[intoc=true,
           program=xindy,
           title={Subject Index}]
\makeindex[intoc=true,
           title={Author Index},
           program=xindy,
           name=names]

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[names]}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}}

\makeindex[intoc=true,
             title={Title Index},
             program=xindy,
             name=titles]

\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:title}{\index[titles]}{#1}}%

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson, worman,geer}
\printindex
\printindex[titles]
\printindex[names]
\end{document}
```

[image: Correct author index]

Comment: I compiled the file with `latexmk`, which runs all required tools automatically. For the required `arara` invocations https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/584633/35864 might be useful, but I'm probably the wrong person to ask about indexing with `arara`.

Comment: it compiled correctly with `arara`, thank you for explaining that the extra braces kept it local, now I know to check for that in the future if issues occur.