# Creating a clickable link to a local file only in source code

Tags: texstudio, external-files, sourcecode, hyperlink, filesystem-access

The following situation:
I use a program for my data analysis. The program creates a project file. From this file I export the graphics I'm including as figures in the TeX code.

Is there a way to insert an executeable link to the project file within - *and only within* - the source code to improve quality of life?

Right now I'm using comments to store this information. \url and \href produce links in the pdf, which I do not want. I'm using TeXstudio.

Comment: Wouldn't that pretty much require support by your used editor/IDE? Or do you mean something like [\write18](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88740/3925)? Also see: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-spawnprog