# PDFlatex not converting eps to pdf ANYMORE

Tags: pdftex, conversion

I observe a very strange behaviour with `PDFlatex`.

I have recently used the beamer to create a presentation. The last compilation (with `PDFlatex`) was done on the 9th of April 2015. Today (July 2015), I wanted to reuse the same presentation but when I have tried to compile it, that does not work.

The problem comes from the fact that the images that I have in .eps are not converted any more to .pdf (like it was done automatically before). I am using Ubuntu and kile as Tex software. In kile I have restored the default options for compilation but without success. I am aware that I can add options like `--shell-escape`, maybe it works I did not try. However since it was working before without any options, I would like to understand why I have a problem now. I also want to add that my images are located in the same folder than my `.tex` file.

Maybe it comes from the updates of ubuntu??? Does anyone already get the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following list is helpful to pin down the problem.

Prerequisites for a conversion of an EPS file in `pdflatex`:

- The EPS file must exist and must be found by the graphics package.
- Working ghostscript installation, especially the ghostscript must be able
  to convert the EPS file to PDF successfully.
- The programs `epstopdf`/`repstopdf`, which are wrappers for calling ghostscript and which are with taking care of the bounding box.
- `graphics.cfg`, which loads package `epstopdf-base` (when shell escape
  is turned on). It's the case for TeX Live and MiKTeX nowadays.
- Restricted shell escape must be turned on (or unrestricted shell escape).
  It can be enabled by command line options. In TeX Live it can be configured
  in the configuration file `texmf.cnf`:

  ```
  % Enable system commands via \write18{...}.  When enabled fully (set to
  % t), obviously insecure.  When enabled partially (set to p), only the
  % commands listed in shell_escape_commands are allowed.  Although this
  % is not fully secure either, it is much better, and so useful that we
  % enable it for everything but bare tex.
  shell_escape = p
  ```

  Restricted shell escape is usually the default.
- When restricted shell escape is used, then `repstopdf` needs to be in the list of programs, which are allowed to run. Example from `texmf.cnf`:

  ```
  % The programs listed here are as safe as any we know: they either do
  % not write any output files, respect openout_any, or have hard-coded
  % restrictions similar or higher to openout_any=p.  They also have no
  % features to invoke arbitrary other programs, and no known exploitable
  % bugs.  All to the best of our knowledge.  They also have practical use
  % for being called from TeX.
  %
  shell_escape_commands = \
  bibtex,bibtex8,\
  extractbb,\
  kpsewhich,\
  makeindex,\
  mpost,\
  repstopdf,\
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that now I have to add
`\usepackage{epstopdf}` to induce a conversion from eps to pdf.

Moreover I have to compile using the `--shell-escape` option as explained in this post [TeXLive 2011: pdfLaTeX does not convert eps to pdf for eps files in subdirectories](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39460/texlive-2011-pdflatex-does-not-convert-eps-to-pdf-for-eps-files-in-subdirectori).

Someone knows why I need to add these packages now?? It was working without them before (3 months ago).

Comment: Maybe you have changed the file `graphics.cfg`. Package `epstopdf-base` is usually loaded from there, if the (restricted) shell escape feature is enabled.